# NoReverseMatch at /index

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to understand why I am seeing a NoReverseMatch error when trying to use [Django Contact Form](https://django-contact-form.readthedocs.org/en/master/install.html#url-configuration).

The error occurs when I add a link using the following syntax to index.html:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></h3>
```

If I use the following hardcoded syntax then no errors occur and the link to the contact form from index.html works as expected.

```
<h3><a href="contact">Contact</a></h3>
```

What I am trying to achieve is similar to what is shown the Django tutorial about [removing hard coded urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates).

The full error I see is:

> NoReverseMatch at /index
>
> Reverse for 'contact' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'
>   not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

In case of need, my abbreviated urls.py is:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'index$', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
    url(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls')'),
 )
```

I know I am missing something obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there is no url with name `contact`.

```
url(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls')'),
```

is url that will map all urls starting with `contact` to the `contact_form.urls`. Official docs don't say how to access `contact` view, but with basic understanding of django we can do something like this:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'index$', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
    url(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls', namespace='contacts')),
 )
```

and the in the template:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'contacts:contact_form' %}">Contact</a></h3>
```

`contact_form` url name is found in the [source code of the module](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-contact-form/blob/master/contact_form/urls.py#L19).

Comment: Perfect! If I could up vote this answer X 100 I would. Thank you so much, I have been looking at this problem for 2+ hours.

Answer (score 2):

when you use {% url 'contact' %} in template, the 'contact' is actually the name of route. In your url patterns there is no route with this name. You should include something like this into your contact_forms.urls.py:

```
url(r'$', views.index, name='contact_index')
```

Also, you should change "contact/" pattern to:

```
url(r'^contact/', include('contact_form.urls', namespace='contacts'))
```

and then use this when creating link in template:

```
{% url 'contacts:contact_index' %}
```

Comment: Note that `r'$'` will match any url. To only match an empty string, you also need to add a start anchor: `r'^$'`.